# YTPlayerView thumbnail custom size

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-javascript-api, ytplayerview

I am using `YTPlayerView` library from `Google`. I want to get the customised size thumbnail of a youtube video for my `iOS` app.

Can anybody help me how I can achieve this? Current it is giving me the same size thumbnail for a video regardless of the size of my `YTPlayerView`.

Answer (score 0):

`YTPlayerView.load` automatically loads its own thumbnail. However, a workaround could be you place a `UIImageView` on top of the `YTPlayerview`. And load the customized thumbnail into that `UIImageview`. You can start playing the video when the `UIImageview` is clicked using `YTplayerview.play`. And then hide the thumbnail. In essence, it would give the effect the video is being played upon clicking your customised thumbnail image. You may have to fine-tune some things to make this solution work elegantly.

To retrieve the image for the customised thumbnail, you can use any of 4 generated images of youtube. They are predictably formatted as follows:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

The first one in the list is a full size image and others are thumbnail images. The default thumbnail image (ie. one of `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`) is:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/default.jpg
```

For the high quality version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg
```

I hope this helps to answer your question.